# PowerShell: single point where I can catch all exceptions

Tags: powershell, exception

I have several PowerShell script files. `a.ps1` 'calls' (via dot operator) `b.ps1` and `c.ps1` scripts.

```
a.ps1    #main
  b.ps1  #helper1 <- need catch error there
  c.ps1  #helper2 <- error is being raised there
```

Is it possible inside `b.ps1` file to catch terminating error that was thrown in `c.ps1` file?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Inside `a.ps1`:

```
. .\b.ps1
. .\c.ps1
```

Inside `b.ps1`:

```
trap {
  Write-Host "my trap block"
}
```

Inside `c.ps1`:

```
throw "test"
```

"my trap block" isn't called in this example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install a `trap` handler in `b.ps1` to handle errors in `c.ps1` if you dot source `b.ps1` so that it is running in the same scope as `a.ps1` e.g.:

```
. .\b.ps1
```

**Update:**  Indeed that doesn't work. It seems that PowerShell isn't honoring the notion of running in a.ps1's scope by dot sourcing.  Not sure that you will be able to do anything better than this:

```
a.ps1 contents:
---------------
. .\b.ps1

trap {
  TrapHandler $_
  continue
}

.\c.ps1

b.ps1 contents:
---------------
function TrapHandler($error)
{
  Write-Host "oops - $error" 
}
```

It looks like the trap handler needs to be in a.ps1 but you can define a trap handling function in b.ps1.  Still, don't think you can control the disposition (break or continue) of the error in this function.

Comment: This doesn't work. See example in the end of my question (after **EDIT**)

Comment: "...but you can define a trap handling function in b.ps1..." - that is my current solution :). But I don't like it very much - to write `trap` block in every script. Still, thanks for suggestions. Seems to be no better reliable solution

Answer (score 0):

That's really weird. Apparently trap doesn't care about scope, exactly.

I don't have a proper solution, but I have an icky workaround:

You could write *this* in a:

```
.([scriptblock]::create(( (gc .\b.ps1 -del `0) + "`n" + (gc .\c.ps1 -del `0) )))
```

Or the same thing, put another way:

```
.( [scriptblock]::create(( @(gc .\b.ps1) + @(gc .\c.ps1) -join "`n" )) )
```

Comment: Its really "icky workaround". In my case there is at least one big problem with this solution - managing scripts' `param()` section